# why does it show aarayindexoutofboundexception on changing the t[n] though it is under limits

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, lambda, linked-list

In line no. `7`, I have declared a `t` variable in lambda expression but on changing the index of `t[n]`, it shows `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` e.g. if I change it to `t[3]`, it prints only `3` numbers though the limit is set up to `6` but changing it to `t[1]`, it works fine.

Not able to exactly understand why as it should work fine until the `t[n]` is under the limit set.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    // write your code here
        ArrayList<Integer> lambda = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6));
        lambda.forEach(e -> System.out.println("mult  " + e*2));
        lambda.forEach(f -> {if (f%2== 0 ) System.out.println("even " +f) ;});
        List <Integer> fib =  new LinkedList<Integer>();
        fib = Stream.iterate(new int[] {2,4},
                t -> new int[]{t[3],t[0]*t[1]})
                .limit(10)
                .map(n -> n[0]).collect(Collectors.toList());

         fib.forEach(x -> System.out.println("fib " + x));
     } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the call to `Stream.iterate` the initial value is the array with two elements and in the `next` value you try to access element at index 3:

```
Stream.iterate(new int[] {2,4},
            t -> new int[]{t[3],t[0]*t[1]})
```

So you need either to increase the size of the initial array, or fix the index:

1. Using 2-element array as initial value and accumulator, fixed index to refer correct element:

```
Stream.iterate(new long[] {2,4}, t -> new long[]{t[1],t[0]*t[1]})
      .limit(10)
      .map(n -> n[0])
      .forEach(System.out::println);
// output
2
4
8
32
256
8192
2097152
17179869184
36028797018963968
0  // overflow of Long value
```

2. Increased array size in both initial and accumulator parameters of `Stream.iterate`:

```
Stream.iterate(new long[] {2,4,5,6,7},  // 5 elements
            t -> new long[]{t[3],t[0]*t[1],t[2],t[1]}) // 4 elements, using max index of 3, referring updated value in t[1]
            .limit(10)
            .map(n -> n[0])
            .forEach(System.out::println);
// output
2
6
4
8
48
192
1536
73728
14155776
21743271936
```

Comment: If you increased only the size of the initial array `new long[] {2,4,5,6,7},` and kept the 2-element array in the `next` value ` t -> new long[]{t[3],t[0]*t[1]}`, you will get the same error due to the same reason.